# Chemical formula for this potential denitrification inhibitor

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am trying to track down a supplier of this compound (a potential fungal denitrification inhibitor to reduce N20 emissions from pastureland), but all I have is its structure from the computational chemistry paper where it was identified. The supplier wants the formula at the very least. I am not a chemist, but hoped someone here could translate the structure into a formula (or a name.)

[image]

Comment: Too short for an answer, but a search using Chemspider (you can draw the structure) gives : http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.1553572.html?rid=b828c58e-9722-42e5-9a00-478cede7fcd7 - so "2-{[4-(1-Piperidinyl)phenyl]amino}-6-propyl-4(1H)-pyrimidinone"

Comment: If you got your answer, feel free to post a self answer. Self answers are appreciated and it helps future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gilleain's comment, the formula for that structure is:

2-{[4-(1-Piperidinyl)phenyl]amino}-6-propyl-4(1H)-pyrimidinone

Thanks to Chemspider's links, I was able to find a supplier. (But unfortunately, the octanol/water partition coefficient is high (3.6) - which means it's considered bio-accumulative under REACH and very unlikely to be approved for field-spreading.)

Comment: The preferred IUPAC name is: 2-[4-(piperidin-1-yl)anilino]-6-propylpyrimidin-4(1H)-one